# Display textbox data from dropdownbox

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

I'm a novice looking to learn by doing - i'm writing a small windows form app which will display various text output based on the selection from a dropdownbox

I have searched for how to do this but so far I've not found an answer. I simply want the IOPS.text value to display in a text box, based on what value has been selected from the combobox

What I have so far is this:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                //Insert values for block size


                {
                  comboBox1.SelectedValue = ("4Kb");
                        ShowIOPS.Text = ("4096");
                }

                { comboBox1.SelectedValue = ("8Kb");
                        ShowIOPS.Text = ("8192");
                    }
                {
                  comboBox1.SelectedValue = ("16Kb");
                        ShowIOPS.Text = ("16384");
                    }
                {
                  comboBox1.SelectedValue = ("32Kb");
                        ShowIOPS.Text = ("32768");
                    }
                { comboBox1.SelectedValue = ("64Kb");
                        ShowIOPS.Text = ("65536"); }
```

Whats happening now is that no matter what combobox value is selected, it displays the botom iops.text value in the textbox

I'm sure I've missed something very very simple and obvious, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like this...

```
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "4Kb")
            {
                ShowIOPS.Text = ("4096");
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "8Kb")
            {
                ShowIOPS.Text = ("8192");

            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "16Kb")
            {
                ShowIOPS.Text = ("16384");
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "32Kb")
            {
                ShowIOPS.Text = ("32768");

            }               
            else
            {
                ShowIOPS.Text = ("65536");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason your code always displays the bottom iops.text value in the textbox is because you're not giving the program selection to use. It currently just goes through each statement and overrides it till the last iops.text gets chosen. You need to use if statements or a switch statement like below, this tells the program what to iops.text to use based on selection:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Insert values for block size
            Switch (comboBox1.SelectedValue)
            {
            case "4Kb":                                  
                    ShowIOPS.Text = ("4096");
                    break;

            case "8Kb":
                   ShowIOPS.Text = ("8192");
                   break;
            case "16Kb":
                    ShowIOPS.Text = ("16384");
                    break;
            case "32Kb":
                    ShowIOPS.Text = ("32768");
                    break;
            case "64Kb":
                    ShowIOPS.Text = ("65536"); 
                    break;
            default:
                    //some error check if none of the above was selected
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: you probably want to be using a switch statement over using a lot if statements for many reasons, including better readability, easier to amend if logic needs changing and switch statement uses less code